# Turn a form into an associative array in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

I have the following form:

```
<form id="editForm">
<input class="span12" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Product name...">
<input class="span12" name="sku" type="text" placeholder="SKU...">
<input name="basePrice" class="span12" type="text" placeholder="Base price...">
</form>
```

How do I turn that into an associative array that can be accessed like the following?

`formArray['name']`, `formArray['sku']`, etc.

Comment: in other words, you want an object with key/value pairs. You'll have to do it manually by iterating over the form inputs or accessing them 1 by 1.

Comment: @imperium2335 Right, that's why i didn't suggest serializeArray.

Comment: Have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/39248551#39248551

Answer (score 15):

Here's a dead-simple way:

```
$.fn.form = function() {
    var formData = {};
    this.find('[name]').each(function() {
        formData[this.name] = this.value;  
    })
    return formData;
};

// use like
var data = $('#editForm').form();
```

This is totally unsafe and just grabs everything with a name, but it should get you started.

Comment: This is a terrific answer. Just check the values server-side and you are good.